# node net module is wrapper for what ?

Tags: node.js, sockets, kernel

This is from the **nodejs** documentation:

> The **net** module provides you with an asynchronous network wrapper.

My understanding is that **net** module is wrapper for native kernel protocol implementations (TCP/IP, UDP... ) together with **socket** interface ?

Am I right ?
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Yes.
The net module provides you with an asynchronous network wrapper. It contains methods for creating both servers and clients (called streams). You can include this module with require('net');